# Why is my text area returning the value 'null'?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textarea

I keep getting an error where I define my text area as t, but the value of t is null and I don't know why. the ID which I'm searching up is correct, but nothing is being returned. I'm trying to get my text area to jump 5 spaces when the user presses the tab button as opposed to the default action which is to change focus to another element.

```js
let t = document.getElementById('txtEditor');

function addTextAreaListener() {
  t.addEventListener("keydown", taKeyPress);
}

function taKeyPress(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode == "9") {
    t.value += "     ";
  }
}
addTextAreaListener();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Outline editor</title>
  <h1>Outline Editor</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="buttons">
    <button type="button" name="btnSave">Save</button>
    <button type="button" name="btnTF">Text formatting</button>
    <button type="button" name="btnLoad">Load</button>

  </main>
  <main>
    <textarea id="txtEditor" rows="30" cols="80"></textarea>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time this script is executed you element with id='txtEditor' is still not created. You better either use 'onload' event:

```
window.onload= function (){document.getElementById("txtEditor")...
```

or place the script into the bottom of the page (bellow body).

Comment: I've linked the javascript file externally to the HTML page, so everything should be located?

Comment: import the js script just before the </body>

Comment: Yes, but the import is in the header - the script will be loaded there as the rendering of the page goes from top to bottom and the variable t will be evaluated before the rendering is reached the body.
In general - place styles in the header and the script at the bottom of the page to avoid strange behaviour.